# delete lines start with " ;"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string in PHP:

```
string(765) " ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian <<>> -t a webtools.hu @217.65.97.38 ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62425 ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3 ;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096 ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;webtools.hu.  IN  A ;; ANSWER SECTION: webtools.hu.   60  IN  A 217.65.97.116 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: webtools.hu.  60  IN  NS  ns2.wwdh.hu. webtools.hu.   60  IN  NS  ns1.wwdh.hu. ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION: ns1.wwdh.hu.    60  IN  A   213.239.206.117 ns2.wwdh.hu.    60  IN  A   217.65.97.38 ;; Query time: 1 msec ;; SERVER: 217.65.97.38#53(217.65.97.38) ;; WHEN: Tue Apr 04 17:25:11 CEST 2017 ;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 129 "
```

I would like to delete all lines start with space and semicolon (;)

I try to use `preg_replace` but it does not give the correct answer.

```
$eredmeny1 = preg_replace('/(^ ;)+/', '', $output);
```

Can you advise me?

Comment: What we see is one single line that begins with ` ;` so applying this kind of regex will return nothing.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I only see a single line there. Does that mean the whole line needs to be replaced? What do you mean by "line"?

Comment: @RiggsFolly If I print it like this: echo "<pre>$eredmeny1</pre>"; it has multiple lines, without pre tags it is only one line

Comment: Then fix it manually. We can't help you if we don't see what you're seeing.

Comment: @Riggs I voted unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = " ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian 
vds
jfgh gdf
 ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian
hgf";
$eredmeny1 = preg_replace("/(?:[\r\n]+|^) ;.*\n/", "", $output);

// Output: vds
//         jfgh gdfhgf";
```

Comment: Thank You, the regex worked together with the explode function. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna read from file and delete all strings, try this code:

```
<?
$sample = ' ;';
$arr = file('text.txt');
$handle = fopen('text.txt','w+');
foreach($arr as $string){
  if(strpos($string,$sample)===false) fwrite($handle,$string);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarity.   I'm not sure you don't want to "explode" the string and gleen the text from the given array.

```
<?php

$output = " ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian <<>> -t a webtools.hu 
@217.65.97.38 ;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- 
opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62425 ;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, 
ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3 ;; WARNING: recursion requested 
but not available ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 
4096 ;; QUESTION SECTION: ;webtools.hu.  IN  A ;; ANSWER SECTION: 
webtools.hu.   60  IN  A 217.65.97.116 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION: webtools.hu.  
60  IN  NS  ns2.wwdh.hu. webtools.hu.   60  IN  NS  ns1.wwdh.hu. ;; 
ADDITIONAL SECTION: ns1.wwdh.hu.    60  IN  A   213.239.206.117 
ns2.wwdh.hu.    60  IN  A   217.65.97.38 ;; Query time: 1 msec ;; SERVER: 
217.65.97.38#53(217.65.97.38) ;; WHEN: Tue Apr 04 17:25:11 CEST 2017 ;; 
MSG SIZE rcvd: 129 ";

$tset = explode(" ;",$output);
foreach($tset as $t){ echo"$t \n";}
?>
```

OR

...maybe you can "exec()"  "sed -ie 's/^ ;//g' "  with the correct POSIX regex.

Comment: Thank you, the explode was great idea!